# putty PrivateKey file for authentication upload option not showing

Tags: putty, private-key

when I installed putty in my system and try to use it . I had stuck with a problem.The problem is putty PrivateKey file for authentication upload option not showing
[image: showing in my system]

I have tried to refer many sites by I did'nt found any solution for this and again reinstalled the putty
[image: I wanted to upload option like this]

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have answered similar question on Super User already: [Unable to browse private key in PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/1752648/213663).

Answer (score 7):

Just had similar issue like yours and I browse SSH->Auth->Credentials then I put the key in there and it worked

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions. This belongs to [su]. And I have answered the question there already: [Unable to browse private key in PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/1752648/213663).

Answer (score 2):

Same issue when following an instruction. But I tried to expand **Auth** even though the instruction didn't said so. I found **Private key file for authentication** in the Credentials. It worked so I guess its okay.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ozYA.png)

Comment: Please do not answer [off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This belongs to [su]. And I have answered the question there already: [Unable to browse private key in PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/1752648/213663).

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below path :

Click on SSH --> Auth --> select Credentials

You will find an option to upload .ppk file

You can refer below screenshots :

[image: 1]